# Laravel 4 - set database.fetch config at runtime

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 3 I could set the database 'fetch' config at runtime (to get the results as an array rather than an object):

```
Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

In Laravel 4, the result is still being returned as an object.

What am I doing wrong?

**[Edit - extra details]**

I decided to test if the config was being set, and also to try identical code segments in Laravel 3 and Laravel 4 side-by-side.

```
//first fetch as object
Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
//Laravel 3 and 4 returns 88 ... expected:
echo PDO::FETCH_CLASS.Config::get('database.fetch');
$users = $users = DB::table('users')->get();
//Laravel 3 and 4 both return an array of objects(stdClass) ... expected
var_dump($users);

//then fetch as array
Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
//Laravel 3 and 4 returns 22 ... expected:
echo PDO::FETCH_ASSOC.Config::get('database.fetch');
$users = $users = DB::table('users')->get();
//Laravel 3 returns an array of arrays ... expected
//Laravel 4 returns an array of objects(stdClass) ... UNEXPECTED!
var_dump($users);
```

Comment: Why can't you modify app/config/database.php and adjust the fetch style there?

Comment: because I need to change the setting dynamically for certain methods in my application only (a few methods need to return arrays, but most of the application needs to return objects).

Comment: @MMacdonald in that case, wouldn't toArray() be what you want? http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#collections

Comment: isn't toArray() only for Eloquent? These methods use the query builder only. It was possible to set fetch dynamically in Laravel 3.

Comment: What do you get if you set it from `config/database.php` file, check it.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 if I set it only in config/database.php and **not** dynamically I get the expected result (an array of arrays returned).

Comment: I've tested it in both ways and it works but not sure why it's not working in your case, anyways, I've gave an answer using an alternative way, so you can use it on runtime.

Comment: You can cast an object to an array by doing `$object = (array)$object;` in PHP.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### TL;DR: Don't use config for run-time changes

The configuration set's the fetch mode on initialization **only**. This is generally true for all Illuminate libraries.

If you need to change the fetch-mode in **run-time**, you need to set this on your connection object rather than in the configuration.

Luckily, we have access to the connection object.

Notice that the `Connection` object has a [`setFetchMode()`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php#L828) method.

### Use the Connection Object Directly

This means in your code you can [get your connection](http://fideloper.com/laravel-multiple-database-connections) and then run `setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` with it prior to querying the DB.

```
// With Query Builder
$query = DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

// With Eloquent model
$user = new User;
$user->getConnection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Comment: @fideloper - thanks. Taylor mentioned in [my Github ticket](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2476) that database.fetch will be deprecated in future. Also covered this in the [Laravel forums](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=13568).

Comment: You might probably want to set the fetch mode back to `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` after fetching the arrays you need. `$query = DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);`

Comment: FYI in 2021, This method is no longer public in the Connection class, hence will throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with this

```
Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

It should work and it does on my local server. If it's not working for some reason then you can use an alternative way to achieve the same result, i.e.

```
function stdToArray($obj)
{
    if (is_object($obj)) {
        $obj = get_object_vars($obj);
    }
    if (is_array($obj)) {
        return array_map(__FUNCTION__, $obj);
    }
    else {
        return $obj;
    }
}
```

If you put this function in your `filter.php` file as a helper function, then you can use it from any where in your `app` just like

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
dd(stdToArray($users));
```

The result will be an array of arrays but `Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` should work and I've checked on my local server, it works just fine.

**Update :** (Even better, to convert the array of objects to an array of arrays)

```
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
$users = json_decode(json_encode($users), true);
dd($users); // an array of arrays
```

**Update :** Why it worked on my local server but not on `OP`'s server, here it's : (**Thanks to fideloper**)

```
// I have this query at first
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
```

Then I've following

```
Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
dd($users); // expected an array of arrays but it was objects
```

But, if i just remove the first `db query` then it just works fine with this

```
// $users = DB::table('users')->get();
Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
dd($users); // expected an array of arrays and I get it
```

So, it means that once you make a query and then you use `Config::set(...)`, it doesn't change the fetch mode because the connection is already made and it's used further. So, this could be the case that, it's not working with `Config::set(...);`, you probably have make the connection/query. So, the solution is [fideloper's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19369644/741747).

```
DB::connection()->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$users = DB::table('users')->get();
dd($users); // an array of arrays
```

Credit goes to `fideloper`.

Comment: You can also just do `$users = (array)DB::table('users')->get();` - http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 thanks - upvoted. I'd like to debug why the official method isn't working on my server before accepting an answer.

Comment: @ceejayoz, Thanks, but will it convert each objects of the array to array ? Maybe not but lemme check right now.

Comment: @MMacdonald, I appreciate it and you are right about the debugging, you should find out why it's not working.

Comment: @ceejayoz, No it `($users = (Array)DB::table('users')->get();)` doesn't work and it's logically right, because result is an array of objects, but `(array)$stdObject` will work.

Comment: **Changing the Config should not be used for run-time changes.** This probably worked because the answerer set the config before doing any queries. In reality, the OP is probably doing queries and THEN trying to change the config for future queries. The difference is that by then, the DB is already initialized with the original config. The DB classes doesn't check after the initialization to see if config was changed.

Comment: @RecoveringSince2003 - thanks. Taylor mentioned in [my Github ticket](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/2476) that database.fetch will be deprecated in future. Also covered this in the [Laravel forums](http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=13568).

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but maybe something like this works.

```
$config = Config::set('database.fetch', PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$config->toArray();
```

Comment: I'm not really following. How does this set the configuration differently to what I posted? For me it just returns an exception: "Call to a member function toArray() on a non-object"