# Laravel 5.1 DB:select toArray()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a large SQL statement that I am executing like so:

```
$result = DB::select($sql);
```

For example

```
$result = DB::select('select * from users');
```

I'd like the result to be an array - but at the moment it returns a structure like so, an array with Objects...

```
Array
(
    0 => stdClass::__set_state(array(
        'id' => 1,
        'first_name' => 'Pavel',
        'created_at' => '2015-02-23 05:46:33',
    )),
    1 => stdClass::__set_state(array(
        'id' => 2,
        'first_name' => 'Eugene',
        'created_at' => '2016-02-23 05:46:34',
    )),
...etc...
```

)

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Seems like you need to cast the stdClass Objects as Array so you can have the structure you are looking for

```
$result = array_map(function ($value) {
    return (array)$value;
}, $result);
```

Comment: Good Idea! Are you sure Eloquent does not provide a function to do it?

Comment: Eloquent does it, but you are using [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries) , not Eloquent

Comment: `$result = array_map(fn($x) => (array)$x, $result);`

Answer (score 34):

The best solutions looking at performance would be changing method how data is grabbed from database:

```
// get original model
$fetchMode = DB::getFetchMode();
// set mode to custom
DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
// get data
$result = DB::select($sql);
// restore mode the original
DB::setFetchMode($fetchMode);
```

Obviously if you want to get all the data as array, it will be enough to change in `config/database.php` from:

```
'fetch'       => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,
```

into

```
'fetch'       => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
```

and then running only:

```
$result = DB::select($sql);
```

will return you multidimensional array instead of array of objects

Comment: This is really advanced. Thanks.

Comment: I've found this answer related to this topic, I think this can improve what @Marcin suggest. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19369644/2848140

Comment: I get this error in Laravel 5.4: `Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::getFetchMode()`.

Comment: That is exactly what I looked for. Thanks.

Comment: I got this error in Laravel Framework 8.26.1 --
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection::setFetchMode()

Comment: This solution no longer works after Laravel 5.4 apparently.

Comment: The `select` method should support a `$mode` param

Answer (score 13):

Here is another approach that is worth to be mentioned:

```
$resultArray = json_decode(json_encode($result), true);
```

Comment: This's only the way around other than listen on even lister laravel,so sad lah.

Answer (score 11):

[`toArray()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-toarray) method converts collection to an array. Models are converted to arrays too:

> The `toArray` method converts the collection into a plain PHP array.
>   If the collection's values are `Eloquent` models, the models will also
>   be converted to arrays

So, I guess you're doing something wrong. If you want more help, please update you question with all related code.

Also, only Eloquent collections (models) have `toArray()` method.

To use this method, use Eloquent:

```
$result = \App\User::all()->toArray();
```

Comment: $result = DB::select($sql)->toArray();

Comment: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function toArray() on array' in ...

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev, I guess that's the answer for aimee's code. Of course it will not work. Please show your code and I'll show you how you can convert it to an array.

Comment: I extended the question, I put example there. Thanks.

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev, I've updated my answer with working Eloquent code equivalent to `$result = DB::select('select * from users');`

Comment: Ok, now it is legit answer that does not help :)

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev, well that's the right way to do it. What you're doing is reinventing a wheel which is always bad.

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin , but I'm using Query Builder , not Eloquent.

Comment: I don't think you read the question completely. Your quoted documentation even proves your answer wrong. The question is about an array of stdClasses. The toArray function does NOT convert those for you to array. You need to map/convert.

Answer (score 4):

For laravel/lumen 5.4 (that uses illuminate/database 5.4):

```
$pdo = DB::getPdo();
$statement = $pdo->prepare($yourQuery);
$statement->setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$statement->execute();
$results = $statement->fetchAll();
```

**Or** listen to Illuminate\Database\Events\StatementPrepared event: [Laravel 5.4 - How to set PDO Fetch Mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44795215/laravel-5-4-how-to-set-pdo-fetch-mode)

Answer (score 3):

you can try this

```
DB::table('commune')->where('Commune','<>', 'ND')->orderBy('Commune')->get()->pluck('Commune');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a collection in order to use `toArray()`, very simple approach:

```
$result = DB::table('users')->get();
$data = collect($result)->map(function($x){ return (array) $x; })->toArray();
```

Comment: The accepted answer uses the same concept of array_map-ing, but without extra conversion to and out from collection. I'm afraid you have not contributed much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$result = DB::select($sql);
$arr = [];
foreach($result as $row)
{
    $arr[] = (array) $row;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. I got: local.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to a member function get() on array'

Comment: UPDATE
exception 'ErrorException' with message 'call_user_func_array() 
expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, class 'Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection' does not have a method 'selectRaw''

Comment: @huuuk, select accepts not only column names: `$users = DB::select('select * from users where active = ?', [1]);` - Also, your examples doesn't work. To make last one get something, you need to remove `->get()`

Comment: @AlexMezenin I'm sorry, I was wrong. You are right. I'm a bit confused wit `Eloquent`

Answer (score 0):

Good to pick through the answers here to understand the reasons. Here's my version that I settled on:

```
$users = collect($users) // turn the top level array into a collection
    ->map(fn($user) => (array) $user) // cast each object to an array
    ->toArray(); // convert top level collection back to an array
```

You had an array of objects. Now you will have an array of arrays. Note that this doesn't do a recursive conversion of the internal array, but since it's only one level deep you're fine.

Answer (score -1):

You can do this way..

At the top

```
use DB;
use PDO;

--------------------

DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // Set the fetch mode as array

$result = DB::select('select * from users');
```

For example, now you can get result like this way.

```
$first_email = $result[0]['email'];
```

Now you can change to default fetch mode.

```
DB::setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS);
```

Answer (score -1):

One tricky and simple way :

```
//Got array in stdClass converting to JSON
$temp1= json_encode($result);


//JSON to Array
$temp2= json_decode($temp1,1);`
```

May be it will help you

Comment: I answered the same way on May 30 '16 at 5:44. You are a bit late. Please read existing answers before posting yours.

Answer (score -1):

Shorthand alternative for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37517871/3026045) answer. Required PHP 7.4 or above

```
$result = array_map(fn ($value) => (array)$value, $result);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use this one. It's worked for me.

```
$query = DB::table('user')->select(['id','name'])->get();
$userlist = $query->toArray();
```

Answer (score -4):

Easiest way is using laravel toArray function:

```
public function toArray()
{
    return array_map(function ($value) {
        return $value instanceof Arrayable ? $value->toArray() : $value;
    }, $this->items);
}
```

Comment: toArray() is method, not just function. And it converts collection to an array. I don't have a collection for starters, I have an array of objects. Only because DB::select($sql); returns array of objects. So your answer is not help.