# Large SQL query takes 10 times more memory in PHP than SQL data

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

So we have an existing system, which we are trying to scale up and running out of memory retrieving close to 3M records.

I was trying to determine how viable is increasing server memory as a stop gap solution, by ascertaining data size returned by the query, by doing something like:

```
select sum(row_size) 
from (
SELECT
    ifnull(LENGTH(qr.id), 0)+
    ifnull(LENGTH(qr.question_id), 0)+
    ifnull(LENGTH(qr.form_response_id), 0)+
    ifnull(LENGTH(qr.`value`), 0)+
    ifnull(LENGTH(qr.deleted_at), 0)+
    ifnull(LENGTH(qr.created_at), 0)+
    ifnull(LENGTH(qr.updated_at), 0)
    as row_size
    FROM
    ....
    LIMIT 500000
) as tbl1;
```

Which returns `30512865` which is roughly 30MB of data.

However when I cross check what PHP actually uses to store the results using:

```
$memBefore = memory_get_usage();
$formResponses = DB::select($responsesSQL, $questionIDsForSQL);
$memAfter = memory_get_usage();
dd($memBefore, $memAfter);
```

I am getting `315377552` and `22403248` which means `292974304` bytes or roughly 300MB of memory usage to store simple array!

I would like to understand why the memory footprint is 10 times the data retrieved, and is there anything I could do to reduce that footprint, short of modifying the API response from back end, and front end to not need the entire result set which will take time.

For context, current implementation uses the above results (returned by `getQuestionResponses`)to transform them into associative array grouped by question_id using Laravel Collections:
`collect($this->questionResponseRepo->getQuestionResponses($questions))->groupBy('question_id')->toArray();`

I am thinking to replace the `collect` with own implementation more memory efficient which will use the array returned from the query to reduce memory inflation by converting that array into Laravel's Collection, but thats still not helping with the array itself taking 300MB for 500k records responses instead of 30MB.

One of the solutions online is to use `SplFixedArray` but I am not sure how to force `DB::select` to use that instead of array?

Another possible solution involves ensuring it returns simple assoc array instead of array of standard classes https://stackoverflow.com/a/37532052/373091
But when I try that as in:

```
// get original model
$fetchMode = DB::getFetchMode();
// set mode to custom
DB::setFetchMode(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$memBefore = memory_get_usage();
$formResponses = DB::select($responsesSQL, $questionIDsForSQL);
DB::setFetchMode($fetchMode);
$memAfter = memory_get_usage();
dd($memBefore, $memAfter, $formResponses);
```

, I get error `Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\MySqlConnection::getFetchMode()` which means apparently it can no longer be done from Laravel> 5.4 :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why do you need to retrieve those 3M records first of all?

Comment: PHP memory management is complex with many moving parts. For example a typical algorithm to dynamically grow an array is to double its capacity each time, also PHP arrays are essentially hash tables so there's overhead there as well. In addition each row is stored as an stdClass which does have its own overheads. Furthermore `memory_get_usage` *returns the amount of memory, in bytes, that's currently being allocated to your PHP script.* so not actual memory usage that your variables are actually taking, so generally is an overestimate. XDebug has good memory profiling tools for more details

Comment: @Kosh Because that's how the system currently works by retrieving all records. And I am currently looking for a quick workaround while refactoring exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem is that you're loading all 3 million records into memory at once. You should instead either process them in chunks or use a cursor.

### Chunking

To chunk records into batches, you can use the Laravel's [chunk](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#chunking-results) method. This method accepts two parameters, the chunk size and a callback that gets passed the subset of models or objects for processing. This will execute on query per chunk.

Here's the example taken from the documentation:

```php
Flight::chunk(200, function ($flights) {
    foreach ($flights as $flight) {
        //
    }
});
```

### Cursor

Alternatively, you can also use the [cursor](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#cursors) method if you only want to execute a single query. In this case, Laravel will only hydrate one model at a time so you never have more than one model (or object if you're not using Eloquent) in memory at a time.

```php
foreach (Flight::where('destination', 'Zurich')->cursor() as $flight) {
    //
}
```